# determine SQL server 2012 connection string

Tags: sql-server

i need to connect to SQL server from node so i need connection string. 
How to define connection strings in SQL server 2012 ? or what are the ones by default ?

Comment: The connection string hasn't changed, it's the same as it was with all previous versions. What are you really asking? Did you try to create a connection and had a problem? Tried to google for the syntax but didn't find something that covers a specific scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I get your question right...

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: yes! but i want to know where to find the value of ID and Password for example

Comment: did you have install your SQL-Server? can you connect with Microsoft Management Studio?

Comment: yes but when i connect to the sql server with node it tels me connection error so i thought i had to enter valid connection string 
here is my initial problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474096/connect-to-sql-server-2012-with-node-js

Answer (score 0):

> The server/instance name syntax used in the server option is the same
>   for all SQL Server connection strings.

```
Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new [universal data link file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e38h511e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (.udl) on your computer and double click the file in order to select provider and enter connection data. This way, you can test the connection and modify the settings accordingly.

Create a new file `a.txt` for instance, and rename this file to `a.udl`

Then follow the steps below to configure connection

> 1. Double-click the universal data link (.udl) file. The Data Link Properties dialog box opens, displaying the following tabs:  Provider,
>      Connection, Advanced, and All. Choose Next to navigate from tab to
>      tab.
> 2. On the Provider tab, select a database provider.
> 3. On the Connection tab, either select the data source name (DSN) of an available Provider, or enter a custom connection string. Valid DSNs
>      for providers that are pre-defined on your system are displayed in the
>      Use Data Source drop-down list.
> 4. Use the Advanced tab to view and set other initialization properties for your data.
>      5.Use the All tab to review and edit all OLE DB initialization properties available for your OLE DB provider.
> 5. Choose OK to save the connection string to the Universal Data Link (.udl) file.

Then open up the file with a **text editor** to access the connection string stored.

Comment: connection succeded but i don't get connection string in a.udl when i open it with text editor :[oledb]
; Everything after this line is an OLE DB initstring
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=dbUsers;Data Source=ICEFOX-PC\NODE

maybe this is related to the fact that i connect to server using windows authentication ?

Comment: This is also a connection string. Have you tried this one with node?

Comment: @abderrahmen and yes it's due to the fact that you use win auth, you can choose to specify username and password.